GetTemplateChild Always Returns Null
I usually like to solve problems by myself but I can't really wrap my head around the following:

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PanelItemBase}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}"
           >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PanelItemBase}">
                    <Grid   x:Name="PART_grid"
                            Width="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Height="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            >
                        <local:PathBase x:Name="PART_pathBase"
                                        Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        Width="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        Height="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        Fill="{Binding Fill, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        Stroke="{Binding Stroke, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        Shadow="{Binding Shadow, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        ShadowDepth="{Binding ShadowDepth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        ShadowDistance="{Binding ShadowDistance, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
 

Whenever I try retrieving template parts by calling GetTemplateChild inside the OnApplyTemplate Override like this:
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    
    _pathBase = GetTemplateChild("PART_pathBase") as PathBase;
    if (_pathBase == null) Debug.WriteLine("PART_pathBase not found in PanelItemBase template.");
    else Debug.WriteLine("PART_pathBase successfully retrieved.");
    
    _grid = GetTemplateChild("PART_grid") as Grid;
    if (_grid == null) Debug.WriteLine("PART_grid not found in PanelItemBase template.");
    else Debug.WriteLine("PART_grid successfully retrieved.");
}

it always returns null, no matter the template part.
I have tried:

isolating the issue
verifying that my Generic.xaml is being applied properly
creating a new file with the same setup

Thanks for any answers in advance!

Try to override OnVisualChildrenChanged to check if proper template content is instantiated.

The items are indeed being added properly and they are working just as fine UNTIL they are being retrieved. The UI also continues working.

Try to inspect the visualAdded parameter using debugger. With your template it should be the PART_grid element. Check if it's FrameworkElement.Name property is properly set to "PART_grid". The code you already posted is ok, so the issue should be somewhere else. Please add more code of the local:PanelItemBase class. Especially, what is a base class for local:PanelItemBase.

Hi there, thank you very much for your input but as it turns out the reason why I wasn't able to fix it was because of the issue being related to my project in general. I don't really know what it was but when I set up a new project with the same environment everything worked fine. Should I just delete the OP or can I somehow mark it as solved? Thanks again!

I think you can safely delete it, since it doesn't have a proper answer and it's very unlikely that it can help anyone else with similar problem.
